# Is the Cisco vulnerability specific to Cisco or is it something in some commonly used library?

Tags: tls, vpn, vulnerability, cisco

I am referring to the vulnerability reported here:

- [Cisco secuirty advisory on "Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Remote Code Execution and Denial of Service Vulnerability"](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20180129-asa1?source=techstories.org)
- [CIS adviory on the same vulnerability](https://www.cisecurity.org/advisory/a-vulnerability-in-cisco-adaptive-security-appliance-software-could-allow-for-remote-code-execution_2018-014/)

Is this in some proprietary code specific to Cisco, or is it something in some underlying SSL/VPN library which may be used by other products also? If I am running some SSL-VPN product from a non-Cisco vendor should I be worried about this vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

[CVE-2018-0101](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-0101) states:

> A vulnerability in the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) VPN functionality of the Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance (ASA) Software could allow an unauthenticated, remote attacker to cause a reload of the affected system or to remotely execute code.

No mentioning of a vulnerability in a generic library whatsoever. Also, looking at the list of affected products/models on that CVE, I don't see any equipment which is running some sort of Linux under the hood to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

[CVE 2018-0101](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-0101) is completely Cisco-specific. In short; there was an issue whereby sending a certain XML packet you would cause the ASA to free a chunk of memory twice thus resulting in arbitrary behaviour. As stated in the talk this is *not* a bug in IKE.

Below are links to a few helpful resources surrounding this vulnerability including the talk by Cedric who discovered this with his co-workers over at [NCCGroup](https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/).

[Research blog](https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2017/september/cisco-asa-series-part-one-intro-to-the-cisco-asa/)

[Cedrics talk](https://www.offensivecon.org/speakers/2018/cedric-halbronn.html)

[Cedrics Slides](https://recon.cx/2018/brussels/resources/slides/RECON-BRX-2018-Robin-Hood-vs-Cisco-ASA-AnyConnect.PDF)

Answer (score 0):

If it was a opensource or common library the CVE would be attached to the library and not the Cisco projects using it.